# D3 Force Drag vertically inverse

Tags: d3.js

I've changed an example of a Force Directed Layout to DIV's instead of SVG's but the vertical drag seems to be inverse and I have no idea why. (Could be the limoncello) :)

http://codepen.io/michaelbell/pen/rxMVmx/

There is nothing very weird about the force code:

```js
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .nodes(nodes)
  .size([width, height])
  .gravity(0)
  .charge(0)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .start();

function tick(e) {
  $div
    .each(cluster(10 * e.alpha * e.alpha))
    .each(collide(.5))
    .style('left', function(d) {
      return x(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x))) + 'px';
    })
    .style('top', function(d) {
      return y(Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y))) + 'px';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because [SVG has a coordinate system](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#InitialCoordinateSystem) with the positive `y` values starting at the top of the page at zero and increasing values go down rather than up. This is accounted for in the `d3.scale.linear` `domain` and `range` for `y` to reverse it.

```
var y =
  d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([height, 0]);
```

Try changing the y scale to be the same orientation as the x scale. For example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxRqVW

```
var y =
  d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, height])
    .range([0, height]);
```